# Display selected listview-image to picturebox with drag&drop

Tags: c#

I've been around a bit longer, but I just can not get it, I want to drag & drop the selected listview-image into a picturebox.

```
   private void listView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (listView1.SelectedIndices.Count == 0)
                return;
            Int32 item = listView1.SelectedIndices[0];
            Image img1 = imageList1.Images[item];
            pictureBox1.Image = img1;
        }
```

Strangely, the wrong image is displayed in the picture box
I hope you can help me.
greetings

Comment: Shouldn't you use the DragDrop of the picturebox? And: Can there be more than one item selected? Finally: You should use the ImageIndex: listView1.SelectedIndices[0].ImageIndex not the Item's ItemIndex! They may be the same, depending of how you add the items and set their ImageIndex, but seemingly are not.

Comment: This not works, because there is no defination for ImageIndex

Comment: Of course there is, but in every ListviewItem. I made a typo, sorry; it is in the Items note their index. jp2's answer gets it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about **SelectedIndices**.

What about **SelectedItems** instead?

```
private void listView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (0 < listView1.SelectedItems.Count)
    {
        var item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
        Image img1 = imageList1.Images[item.ImageIndex];
        pictureBox1.Image = img1;
    }
}
```

Edit - OK, you are a noobie. That's fine. I just didn't realize.

First, make sure the **ImageList** in your designer has images in it.

1. Select the `imageList1` control
2. Click on the **Images** collection
3. Add your images
4. Click OK

[image: image list]

Next, set the **ListView** control to use this **ImageList**:

[image: list view set image list]

With the **ListView** control still selected...

1. Select the `listView1` control
2. Click on the **Items** collection
3. Add a new **ListViewItem**
4. Give it some Text (I used "Item 1")
5. Select an ImageIndex

[image: list view]

This is quite a lot to write out just for a simple answer. You might be better off looking at Microsoft's Walk Through document here:

[Walkthrough: Performing a Drag-and-Drop Operation in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/walkthrough-performing-a-drag-and-drop-operation-in-windows-forms)

Comment: I get this error  

`System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "InvalidArgument=Value `

Comment: `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "InvalidArgument = Value with value -1 is invalid for index.
Parameter name: index "`  this line:  `Image img1 = imageList1.Images[item.ImageIndex];`      Nothing happens on listView1_DragDrop only on listView1_SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: That means your **ListViewItem** `item` does not have an **ImageIndex** assigned to it from the **ImageList** control. Fix that, and the error should go away.

Comment: Can you tell me how I do it?

Comment: How do you add the Items??

Comment: All items are added, but I cant select the imageindex there is none, only the stateimageindex

Comment: You need to __set__ it while of after adding the Items! And you need to set the Large- or SmallImageList.

Comment: Edited the answer to add pictures and links

Comment: lol - you will need to look into how to do Drag-N-Drop. It is a lengthy tutorial, too.

Comment: I didn't see that link on the end xD thanxs.

Comment: Of course as long as you only need one PBox, why drag&drop?? selecting will suffice!